# Motor with Water Pump Through Shaft?

Tags: motors, pumps

I am attempting to drive a device with a motor, but also require water input.

Is there such a device that serves as both a drive motor with a water pump through the motor's shaft?

In essence, it would have the functions of both a motor and a water pump in one.

Comment: Motors and pumps are often bolted together or share a common shaft.

Comment: Are you trying to drive a device and a pump with  the same motor along the same axis, or do you want to pump water *through* the rotational axis of the motor? I don't quite understand your requirement. Maybe a simple drawing?

Comment: Yes, drive a continuous flow centrifuge with input/output slurry. Like, iCon 150